# Stability of Mercaptoundecanoic acid and thiol-PEG stored as solids

Tags: experimental-chemistry, surface-chemistry

I am planning to use Mercaptoundecanoic acid (MUA, 98%) and thiol-PEG (O-[2-(3-Mercaptopropionylamino)ethyl]-O′-methylpolyethylene glycol) for functionalisation of gold nanoparticles.
The SDS recommends storage under inert gas conditions for both chemicals and either in the freezer or fridge as the chemicals are sensitive to air.

I am unsure on how sensitive the chemicals are and what part (for example the thiol group or the PEG part) are sensitive.
Storing solids under inert gas conditions is quite a hassle (always going into the glovebox takes forever to simply weigh out chemicals) so I was wondering if someone has input for:

1. what part of the molecule is 'sensitive' and will degrade if not stored/handled under inert gas?
2. Is there a smooth way to store solids under inertgas outside the glovebox (a potential product that I could order would help a lot! - like a gas-tight vial?)
3. Could these chemicals maybe be stable in some solvent (like ethanol?) so that the handling under inert gas gets easier?

Thanks!